# How to calculate the element on the scroll in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the UI like this, there're some image elements on the scroll and I want to scroll horizontal, if the scroll at the postion which is display 4th image fully, the number will be 4/5 and if the scroll at the postion which is display 5th image fully, the number will be 5/5 ex. My screen is only display 3 items fully at the beginning because of my UI is used for mobile, max-width: 414px. I think I have to use kind of: scrollWidth or scrollLeft,... .But I don't have any idea. Anyone can suggest the solution? Sorry if my english is not good. I'm doing in ReactJS. Thank you very much.

https://ibb.co/vBqSDyH

link video: https://storyxpress.co/video/kt9peaxlihzbthbcj

Comment: Can you please put the minimal reproducible example on your question?

Comment: Hi @DhanaD. I've just add the video link, kind check and help me, thank you.

Comment: @Vuledev2905, a video is not a [mre]. Please read [ask]. We're not going to watch a video just to understand your question. Please provide some _code_.